# Why is Hestenes-Powell-Rockafellar penalty function differentiable?

Tags: derivatives, lagrange-multiplier

They say the penalty function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f(x) = \frac{\rho}{2}\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\max\{0,\mu_j + \rho x_j\}\right)^2$$ is differentiable and even give a formula for the gradient
$$ \nabla f(x) = -\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n \max\{0,\mu_j + \rho x_j\}e_j,$$
for the context you can consider $\mu=(\mu_j)$ and $ \rho>0$ as constants. I can kinda see how the derivative would become something like that if the function $\max\{0,\mu_j + \rho x_j\}$ was differentiable, but why is it? There is a maximum. Shoulnd't it be non-differentiable on the places where the scalar functions $0$ and $\mu_j + \rho x_j$ meet?

Comment: $x\mapsto\max\{0,x\}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, but $$x\mapsto\max\{0,x\}^2=\begin{cases}x^2,&x\geq 0\\0&x\leq 0\end{cases}$$ is everywhere differentiable. This is because you are pasting two functions, $y=0$ and $y=x^2$, that have the same value and derivative at $x=0$.

Comment: I see, so this penalty function is only once differentiable, then?

Comment: Yes. The derivative of $g(x)=\max\{0,x\}^2$ is continuous but no more differentiable at $x=0$. However, $g'(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous, which is almost as good as saying that $g'(x)$ has a bounded derivative.